# HTML table layout question

Tags: html

If I have 3 columns for example:

```
<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Know the width</td>
      <td></td>
</tr>
```

In the 2nd column I know the width, and want this centered for example 777, and want the other 2 sides to take up what is left of the screen (in equal shares), how is this done?

This: simply doesn't work:

```
  <tr>
        <td width="*%" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="777"></td>
        <td width="*%"></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`colgroup` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.1):

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="*">
        <col width="30">
        <col width="*">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Know the width</td>
          <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok - lol I see you had a typo :) +1 it works now, and accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Using floats would work better in this case. You could setup the middle float to have a fixed size, and the other two can be setup to fill the rest (I don't remember the exact css statements)

Comment: I don't see how you could do that. How would you tell it to make the left and right floats the same, but unknown, size? Maybe there's a way but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with css2 browsers. The textaling is needed in the body for IE6.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body{text-align:center;}
        #CenteredDiv{width:400px;margin:auto;background-color:silver;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="CenteredDiv">Centered Div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

T